# Angular graphql adds carriage returns in request

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo

It seems like graphql is adding carriages returns to my json request. It also added _typename but I got rid of it using addTypename: false in graphql.module.ts. How can I get rid om carriage return character?

In graphql.module.ts

```
export function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink) {  
  return {    
    link: httpLink.create({uri}),
    cache: new InMemoryCache({
      addTypename: false
    }),
  };
}
```

In home.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Apollo } from "apollo-angular";
import gql from "graphql-tag";

@Component({
  selector: "app-home",
  templateUrl: "./home.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./home.component.css"]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  statemind: any[];
  loading = true;
  error: any;

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apollo
      .query<any>({
        query: gql `{statemind{issue{person{firstname lastname}}}}`
      })
      .subscribe(
        ({ data, loading }) => {
          this.statemind = data && data.statemind;
          this.loading = loading;
        },
        error => {
          this.loading = false;
          this.error = error;
        }
      );
  }
}
```

I get

```
error: "Bad Request"
message: "JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_OBJECT token↵ at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 35]"
path: "/v1/graphql"
status: 400
```

If I look under Network in Developer tools in Chrome it seems like there are carriage returns added to the query:

```
operationName: null, variables: {},…}
operationName: null
query: "{↵  statemind {↵    issue {↵      person {↵        firstname↵        lastname↵      }↵    }↵  }↵}↵"
variables: {}
```

Comment: why do you think it is the problem ? just bad query syntax ... test it in the graphiql/playground

Comment: @xadm Query works in postman

Comment: https://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Source-Text.Ignored-Tokens

Comment: try to add 'query' word in query 'body' ... `query: gql `query {statemind{i...` - not always required but can be a source of this problem

Comment: show raw request body

Comment: @xadm Tried adding query word, still not working

Comment: show raw `request payload 'view source'` - try to use in postman ... error was about `variables` not parsed as string (why? it should be an object) ... it's jsonencoded with query, can be `null` but also `{}` - probably your API/server doesn't support this variant